# Assigning actions to individual objects in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I do this without having a million if then statements?

Comment: Can you be a tad more specific?

Comment: This is highly data dependant. What are you using as your data source for the picker view? Also do you need to call different methods for each option, or simply perform a data dependant calculation etc?

Comment: can somebody close this, I figured out how to do it.  Sure it's all if then else statements, but it seems to be pretty much the only way I was able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only way I could do it is with if then else statements, oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Please define “actions”. I suppose you could use an array of `SEL`s if they're all targeted to the same object, or one of `NSInvocation` objects otherwise.

Comment: IBActions, or voids, doesn't matter which